# Java - Special character is being encoded twice

Tags: java, encoding, rest-assured

I am writing a test in Java that sends a request to an api. The url includes a `#` which should be getting encoded as `%23`.

However I can't get that %23 to show up accurately in the url.

```
public static void addRecords(JSONObject creds, String subsection, String jsonFile) {
    String body = readFile("files/" + jsonFile);
    given()
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, JSON)
        .header(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER_TOKEN + creds.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN))
        .body(body)
        .post(BASE_API_URL_V1 + "/setup/" + subsection + "/records")
        .then()
        .statusCode(SC_ACCEPTED);
  }
```

When running the below the url gets translated to `/v1/setup/test` so it removes the hashtag completely.

```
    addRecords(creds, "test#v2'", VALID_DATA_JSON);
```

When running the below the url gets translated to `/v1/setup/test%2523/records` so it encodes everything.

```
    addRecords(creds, "test%23v2", VALID_DATA_JSON);
```

What I need is `/v1/setup/test%23v2/records`

Comment: How should we know without seeing your code?

Comment: I've added the code with additional information.

Comment: Ok, close vote retracted.

Comment: What type of Object does `given()` return? I'm trying to find out what post() does

Comment: The library being used is doing it. Please specify the library?

Comment: `given()` returns a RequestSpecification. It's using RestAssured, or `com.jayway.restassured`

Comment: The RestAssured libraries' downloads are broken, I am unable to download them in order to recreate your issue. Also, is your RestAssured up to date? I don't see a `post(String)` method in the docs. However, reading the docs for the URI class, it appears that that may be the route you want to take. Instead of `.post(String)` try `.post(new URI(String))`. As I mentioned, I can't test this, so I won't post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for trying to recreate. I tried that route of using URI and saw the same behavior. The issue was that this library is attempting to encode the URL but for some reason does not function well with a `#` so after some digging I found that I could write this `.urlEncodingEnabled(false)` on the `given()` and just hard code the encoding for `#`

Answer (score 1):

```
 given()
        .urlEncodingEnabled(false)
```

Adding this flag allowed me to hardcode the url without worrying about the library encoding the `%` when executing `addRecords(creds, "test%23v2", VALID_DATA_JSON);`